# Is there a way to automatically append data frame columns below each other into one column within large list of data frames?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a large list with thousands of data frames included in it. These data frames have multiple columns each. Thereby, I want to automatically bind in each of these data frames the columns into one column. This means that they are appended below each other as shown below. Thereafter, I would transform the list to a data frame which would have varying column lengths due to the different number of columns within each element in the original list.

From this:

```
y1 y2
1  4
2  5
3  6
```

To this:

```
y1
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

This should be done for each element in the list, whereby the solution needs to take into account that there are thousands of different data frames, which cannot be mentioned individually (example):

```
df1 = data.frame(
  X1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  X1.2 = c(4, 5, 6)
)
 df2 = data.frame(
  X2 = c(7, 8, 9),
  X2.2 = c(1, 4, 6)
)
df3 = data.frame(
  X3 = c(3, 4, 1),
  X3.2 = c(8, 3, 5),
  X3.3 = c(3, 1, 9)
)
 
listOfDataframe = list(df1, df2, df3)
```

Final output:

```
df_final = data.frame(
  X1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  X2 = c(7, 8, 9, 1, 4, 6),
  X3 = c(3, 4, 1, 8, 3, 5, 3, 1, 9)
)
```

Another problem underlying this question is that there will be a differing number of rows, which I do not know how to account for in the data frame, as the columns need to have the same length.

Thank you in advance for your help, it is highly appreciated.

Structure of list within R:
[image: List L with data frame elements]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `unlist` after looping over the `list` with `lapply`

```
lst1 <- lapply(listOfDataframe, \(x)
   setNames(data.frame(unlist(x, use.names = FALSE)), names(x)[1]))
```

-output

```
lst1
[[1]]
  X1
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  6

[[2]]
  X2
1  7
2  8
3  9
4  1
5  4
6  6

[[3]]
  X3
1  3
2  4
3  1
4  8
5  3
6  5
7  3
8  1
9  9
```

If we need to convert the `list` to a single data.frame, use `cbind.na` from `qPCR`

```
do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, lst1)
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  7  3
2  2  8  4
3  3  9  1
4  4  1  8
5  5  4  3
6  6  6  5
7 NA NA  3
8 NA NA  1
9 NA NA  9
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had to edit the example, yet your code ran through. Would there be a possibility to keep the names of the columns as shown in the final output above (X1, X2, X3 instead of always y1)?

Comment: @LB. Are you looking for a single data.frame, but the lengths are different

Comment: thank you very much! I was indeed looking for a single data frame, but given the differences in lengths your solution seems to provide the only answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tidyverse solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
listOfDataframe %>% 
  map(~.x %>% stack(.)) %>% 
  map(~.x %>% select(-ind))
```

```
[[1]]
  values
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6

[[2]]
  values
1      7
2      8
3      9
4      1
5      4
6      6

[[3]]
  values
1      3
2      4
3      1
4      8
5      3
6      5
7      3
8      1
9      9
```